# Is there any shorter way to write this merger of hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two hashes. The first hash should be prioritized. It should be overwritten by the second hash only when it is `nil` or blank.

```
main_hash.merge!(option_hash) do |key, main_hash, option_hash|
  main_hash.presence || option_hash.presence
end
```

Comment: Try deleting non-present entries in the first, then merge to the second. Use `delete_if`.

Comment: A hash cannot be `nil` or `blank`. It seems that you are referring to the values of the first hash's keys. You need to clarify that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your code, which is fine, but use curly braces for the block and shorter block variables. And you don't need the second `presence`

```
main_hash.merge!(option_hash){|_k, h1, h2| h1.presence || h2}
```

`#merge!` (and `#merge`) with a block only invokes the block to handle cases where a key is present in both hashes. Where `option_hash` keys are not present in `main_hash`, the key/value pair is simply inserted.

You can use `#merge!` with a block to do some neat tricks, like setting up a combined total of hash values.

```
hash_1 = {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}
hash_2 = {b: 1, c: 1, d: 1}

hash_1.merge!(hash_2{|_k, v1, v2| v1 + v2}
=> {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 2, :d => 1}
```

Comment: Hi, @CarySwoveland you mean explain how the block works more explicitly?  Edited answer. Cheers

Comment: @CarySwoveland okey dokey

Answer (score 1):

This is shorter, but I think your way is more readable.

```
main_hash   = {a:1, b:nil, c:3}
option_hash = {a:5, b:2, c:8}

main_hash   = option_hash.merge(main_hash.reject{|_,v| v.blank?})

#=> {a:1, b:2, c:3}
```

You could do it this way and give the result a variable name that makes what is happening a bit clearer like `merged_main_option_hash` instead of just `main_hash`

Answer (score 0):

```
[1] pry(main)> main_hash = { key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: '', key4: nil }
=> {:key1=>1, :key2=>2, :key3=>"", :key4=>nil}
[2] pry(main)> option_hash = { key2: 2.2, key3: 3, key4: 4 }
=> {:key2=>2.2, :key3=>3, :key4=>4}
[3] pry(main)> main_hash.reject!{ |key, value| value.blank? }.merge!(option_hash) { |key, main_hash_value, option_hash_value| main_hash_value }
=> {:key1=>1, :key2=>2, :key3=>3, :key4=>4}
[4] pry(main)>
```

Refer [apidock:merge!](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge%21), [apidock:reject!](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/reject%21)  for more details.

Comment: It's a good attempt but if the `main_hash_value` is nil or an empty string it doesn't get replaced, so it doesn't meet OPs requirement.

Comment: Your answer would be easier to read if you removed pry's prompts. Also, it is customary to show return values beginning `#=>` or `# =>`, so that others can run copied and pasted code without the return values causing exceptions.